# ERR! parse-server-push-adapter APNS cannot find vaild connection

Tags: node.js, heroku, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

Whenever i use the following cloud code to send a push notification on Parse Server 2.2.24

```
Parse.Push.send({
     where: query,
     data: {
        alert: "You have a new comment on " + rift.get("title")
     }
     }, { useMasterKey: true }).then(() => {
        console.log('Push ok');
     }, (e) => {
        console.log('Push error', e);
});
```

I get the following logs with verbose = 1 set on heroku.

```
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783331+00:00 app[web.1]: verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /api/1/push: {
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783333+00:00 app[web.1]:   "headers": {
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783334+00:00 app[web.1]:     "X-Parse-Push-Status-Id": "NbZCxyCOgc"
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783334+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783335+00:00 app[web.1]:   "response": {
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783336+00:00 app[web.1]:     "result": true
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783336+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2016-11-06T05:08:06.783337+00:00 app[web.1]: } X-Parse-Push-Status-Id=NbZCxyCOgc, result=true
2016-11-06T05:08:06.787076+00:00 app[web.1]: Push ok
2016-11-06T05:08:06.788233+00:00 app[web.1]: verbose: sending push to 1 installations
2016-11-06T05:08:06.789569+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Notification transmitted to 443d4d770217648350c5c7cd7bb22d2da77223e23c06f3eb016b2e2ca76d6202
2016-11-06T05:08:06.790600+00:00 app[web.1]: verbose: sent push! 1 success, 0 failures
2016-11-06T05:08:06.867209+00:00 app[web.1]: ERR! parse-server-push-adapter APNS cannot find vaild connection for 443d4d770217648350c5c7cd7bb22d2da77223e23c06f3eb016b2e2ca76d6202
2016-11-06T05:08:06.868965+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2016-11-06T05:08:06.928135+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Connected
```

So it says it was sent successfully (we recieve NO notification to the device) and we get an ERR! parse-server.... for every device token registered from a valid device on a app distributed on Apple's TestFlight Application. I have read multiple posts regarding ways to fix this and have tried everything out there but nothing works. IF anyone has any insight on why this could be happening please let me know! I will be ever grateful

our index.js has the following config setup... we have checked the production cert and even rejected all our certs and generated new ones just to be sure.

```
push: {
     ios: {
      pfx: 'cert-prod.p12',
      bundleId: 'a.bundle.id'  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. Did you make sure the path to the pfx file is a complete path? I used the path module to remedy this:

```
var path = require('path');
  opts.push.ios = {
    // The filename of private key and certificate in PFX 
    pfx: path.join(__dirname, env.IOS_PUSH_PFX),
    bundleId: env.IOS_BUNDLE_ID
}
```

Reference from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3025#issuecomment-258957541